# Integrating paypal using javascript

Tags: api, paypal

I want to integrate paypal on my website using javascript. return the response (true, false) from paypal.

Comment: And what is your question? What have you done so far?

Answer (score 0):

Please refer following links:

[Login with Paypal javascript integration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16901006/login-with-paypal-javascript-integration)?
[Paypal Java script integration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19630956/paypal-java-script-integration)?
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/identity/button-js-builder/?
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/products/?

Comment: i have used these link but i can not get result. actually i want to use payment gaytway for iphone. plz help me.